# How to turn a basic class library into a WCF Service Library

Tags: wcf, visual-studio

I was trying to copy the functionality of an existing WCF service library to use it as a template for a new WCF service library.  Since I was going to cut and paste all the code that I needed, and I didn't want it to create the default service stubs, I didn't start it by using the built-in "WCF Service Library" project template.  I just added a new blank project to my solution, using the "Empty Project" template.

I then created two new blank .cs code files to my project to hold the interface and class for my service, and copied/pasted the Interface and Class code from my original WCF service library project, and made the alterations that I needed to make.

The new project compiles fine, however...

1) If I go into the project properties, the "WCF Options" section does not appear, as it does in my original WCF service library.

2) With the original WCF service libary project, I could right-click on it and select Debug->Start New Instance, and it would automatically start it using WCF Service Host.  With the new project, if I try that, it says, "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly".

How do I get Visual Studio (I'm using 2012 Professional) to see this project as a true WCF class library, short of starting over and using the "WCF Service Library" project template?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the ProjectExtensions section from your `project` file

This is from one of my VS2010 projects.

```
  <ProjectExtensions>
      <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699}">
        <WcfProjectProperties>
          <AutoStart>True</AutoStart>
        </WcfProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

If I remove it, the `WCF Options` properties section goes away.

EDIT:

I did a comparison of an Empty project to a WCF Service Library, and found that you also need to add this to your project to get the WCF Options to appear in the project properties

```
<ProjectTypeGuids>{3D9AD99F-2412-4246-B90B-4EAA41C64699};{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-5ABD9991F28F}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

There is another entry in WCF (and not in the Empty project)

```
<StartArguments>/client:"WcfTestClient.exe"</StartArguments>
```

which I'm assuming is needed when you do the

> Debug->Start New Instance

There is other stuff that you will need however, such as a reference to `System.ServiceModel`.

To be honest, I think you'd be better off using the proper `WCF Service Library` template and cutting out stuff you don't want, rather than trying to figure out what you do need.

Comment: I tried adding this to my project file, but it did not make any difference.  I still have the same two issues.