# Visual Studio Express - Missing Project Subtype prevents opening of project

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

Am trying to create a WCF project by following the walkthrough here ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3, but got stuck at the first steps.

Bad - VSE Windows Desktop does not have the WCF service library templates.

Good - VSE Web Developer does, so I set up the WCF project in VSE Web Developer

Bad - Cannot open the WCF project in VSE Windows Desktop

Good - Find out that you can copy templates from VSE Web Developer Folders to VSE Windows Desktop, and I do

Good - VSE Windows Desktop now has WCF service library templates, so I try to create a new WCF project. VSE seems to comply, sets up the project folder ... but then

Bad - ... throws the error ...

```
The project file '... WcfService1.csproj' cannot be opened.

There is a missing subtype.

Subtype:'{blah blah}' us unsupported by this installation.
```

I even tried turning it off and turning it on again.

What next?

Comment: A WCF Service Library is nothing more than a class library (DLL).  The project template might make it easier to get up and running, but rather than running through all the hoops you did, simply create a class library project in VSE Windows Desktop.

Comment: @Tim - I can't. VSE Windows Desktop does not have he WCF service library templates, so I can't even create a WCF project. Do you mean something else?

Comment: You might want to see this related (duplicate?) question for some of the hurdles you face. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14698258/how-to-turn-a-basic-class-library-into-a-wcf-service-library/14698420#14698420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, a WCF Service Library is nothing more than a **class library** - the WCF Service Library project template just has additional stuff to make it quicker to set up the project.  You can do the exact same thing by creating a class library.

Go to File -> New Project on the menu.  In the window that opens up, expand Visual C#, then select Windows and select Class Library from the list in the center, give it a name and then click OK.

[image]

You'll have to add the Interface and the config settings for the service, but you should be able to copy and paste from the article you're following.   Once that is done, voila, you have a WCF Service Library.

**Edited for more details**

The only thing the WCF Service Library template gives you is a boilerplate for a WCF Service Library - that includes the .cs file for the service implementation, the .cs file for the service contract (interface) That the service implements and an app.config file that has the necessary `<system.serviceModel>` entries.

Sticking with the article you linked to in your original post, here's how to do this without the template.

Step 1 and 2.  Follow what I had above - create the class library.  VS will create the project and you will see a file named class1.cs.  This will be your service class.  Rename it to WCFServiceLibrary1.cs if you desire.

Next add an interface and name it `IWCFServiceLibrary1`.  This will be your service contract.  You will need to update the `WCFServiceLibrary1.cs` file and add `: IWCFServiceLibrary1` after the `public class WCFServiceLibrary1`, so it looks like this:

```
public class WCFServiceLibrary1 : IWCFServiceLibrary1
```

In the interface, add the `[ServiceContract]` attribute above the interface, like this:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWCFServiceLibrary1
```

You will also want to add a reference to `System.ServiceModel` and `using System.ServiceModel` to your class and interface.

Step 3 and 4.  Copy the code in the article to the proper files.

Step 5:  You can test the service by hitting F5 and running the WCFTestClient.

You should then be able to follow the rest of the article.

It takes a little longer this way, but you will also gain a better understanding of what the WCF Service Library is.

Comment: Tried that. Set up a new Class Library in VSE for Windows Desktop and started copying over the items from VSE for Web (clunky, but trying to locate the problem). BUT, could not create an item "Web Service .asmx". In fact VSE For Windows Desktop has none of the items under the "Web" node for "Create New item". How do I get those items in there? PS I looked in the linked articles, which talk about editing an XML file, but where is it?

Comment: Ok.  First, stop trying to copy over things from VSE for Web.  Desktop has everything you need to create this WCF Service Library, it's just not packaged up in a neat template.  ASMX != WCF - ASMX is legacy technology and should not be used for new development.  Give me a few minutes and I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks for your patience. I went through your steps, but got stuck at Step 5. F5 (on the class library) gives the following error message "A project with an Output Type of Class Library cannot be started directly. In order to debug this project, add an executable project to this solution which references the library project. Set the executable project as the startup project." I guess I need the next step in the MSDN walkthrough to drive the class library.

Comment: No go - The next step in the walkthrough requires "Add a service reference", but nothing is showing up on "Discover", even if I add the WcfService1 project to the solution. It looks to me like I have the files, but no mechanism to say "use these files to set up a service". Also, VSE for Windows Desktop has no options for "Web" like VSE for Web (unsurprisingly), so no mechanism to choose a server (e.g. IIS Express) or to set up a localhost. Do I have to manually code something in VSE for windows desktop to create a mock server/localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Expectation management - I was expected to go through all the steps in the walkthough, but they might not be necessary (which is implied in the answers given). So, I tried a bare-bones set up, described here ...

[Is it possible to start exploring WCF using Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop 2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886931/set-up-bare-bones-wcf-project-in-visual-studio-express-2013-for-windows-desktop)