# Is it possible to start exploring WCF using Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop 2013?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2013

Can you set up a bare bones WCF project in Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop C#

The walkthrough described in the MS Getting Started tutorial (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712(v=vs.110).aspx) refers to Visual Studio (NOT the express edition), which has templates that are not available in Visual Studio Express (`WDExpress.exe`), specifically **WCF Service Library**.

How do you start something similar in `WDExpress.exe` without the templates?

Incidentally, I've tried copying templates over from Visual Studio Express for Web 2013 (`VWDExpress.exe`), but without success.

Comment: I don't see a question here? It is perfectly acceptable to Self-Answer, see http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.  However, you should actually provide the question and answer in the standard format, not include the answer in the question post.

Comment: Fair comment, but it's taken me over a week to get this far and it was either this or asking dozens of possibly unanswerable questions and generating many duplicate responses.

Comment: Post reformatted as a question, and suggested workaround given as a n answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible workaround for http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386386.aspx using Visual Studio Express 2013.

All the steps are carried out in VSE 2013 for Windows Desktop (`WDExpress.exe`)

- Step 1 - Start a new project using the template for `Class Library` - it should generate a project with the default name `ClassLibrary1`
- Step 2 - Go to `References` (in `Solution Explorer`) and add references to `System.ServiceModel` and `System.Runtime.Serialization`
- Step 3 - Create a new class called `WCFServiceLibrary1.cs` with the following content

```html
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class WCFServiceLibrary1 : IWCFServiceLibrary1
    {
        public string GetData(string value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }
    }
}
```

- Step 4 - Create a new class called `IWCFServiceLibrary1.cs` with the following content

```html
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [ServiceContract] 
    public interface IWCFServiceLibrary1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(string value);
    }
}
```

- Step 5  - You need a client to run the WCF, so create a Windows form, which will have the default name `Form1.cs`, and add three controls; a textBox, (`textBox1`), a label (`label1`), and a button (`button1`)
- Step 6 - in [Design] mode, double click on `button1` and edit the action so that `Form1.cs` looks like this

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClassLibrary1.WCFServiceLibrary1 client = new ClassLibrary1.WCFServiceLibrary1();
            label1.Text = client.GetData(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

- Step 7 - add a Main class called `Program.cs` with the following content

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            Application.Run(form);
        }
    }
}
```

- Step 8 - Open the `Application` tab in project properties (`PROJECT >> ClassLibrary1.properties`) and set `Output Type` to `Windows Application` and `Startup Object` to `ClassLibrary1.Program`
- Step 9 - F5 will launch the form, which will behave as described at the end of the walkthrough under `To build a client application`

So, what this method does NOT do is go through "Testing the Service" in the walkthrough. Also, it shortcuts a few steps and it bundles the WCF in the same project as the Windows form. Hopefully, it provides bare-bones working code that you can develop and adapt for your application.